# Excel to Powerpoint - looking for a helpful nudge

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint

Good Morning,

I have a C# agent which runs periodically and updates certain values in a particularly important spreadsheet, the reason that this spreadsheet is updated is that periodically someone will manually go into this .xls file and print screen the worksheets and paste them in to a Powerpoint presentation template as images.

These 'images' aren't charts, nor tables, simply ranges of cells that are coloured etc in the spreadsheet - and what I'm looking to do is basically automate this by customising my agent so that everytime it updates the spreadsheet, it 'print screens' a certain range that I specify and copies it as an image into the .ppt file.

I appreciate this question lacks a code example, and I'm not expecting someone to 'do it for me', any advice or pointers on how I might accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Also VSTO is not an option unfortunately (work environment).

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may not have the ability to control how other people create their PowerPoint slides, but if they want a specific range of cells to update to match what the excel sheet is currently, they can Ctrl-C the section then Paste Special.

I know your question asked about automating a print screen capture of the cell range, but would this work for you? Or must there be no possibility of an accidental update, or some reason it must be an image?

The linked section will automatically update if the file is open and if it isn't it will ask if you want to update the links on opening the PowerPoint. Or right-click on the object in the slide and update link.

[image]

Comment: Hi datatoo, there are no 'restrictions' that it must be an image, I just need to programmatically take a range of cells and get them into a template Powerpoint file each time the agent runs, the cells don't need to have any interactivity with Excel from PowerPoint after that, they are just for display purposes.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand. Does the range of the cells change, or just the content?

Comment: Just the content changes, not the range itself - basically just want to 'snapshot' that range everytime I run the agent and copy it across to a particular PPT slide. :)

Comment: linking to the content range sounds easier than capturing a new image each time, since it will automatically update

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing it too reccently.

It might give you an idea.

Put an Alternative.Text to your shape in PowerPoint, it might help you place your new image in the correct place.

[C# Paste HTML to Excel or PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782784/c-sharp-paste-html-to-excel-or-powerpoint/15782785#15782785)

[Showing HTML in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196954/showing-html-in-powerpoint)