# Insert a value from Excel cell to Word document

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have two documents, one Word and other Excel document(*word.docx*  and *excel.xlsx*). In a Word document, I have something like " My salary for this month is *(empty)*, and I worked *(empty1)* days." So that instead of *(empty)* insert a value of, for example, cell **B12** from Sheet1, and instead of *(empty1)* insert a value of cell **F10** from Sheet2.

Is it possible?

Comment: This post might help, but I'd recommend creating a consolidated sheet for use with the mail merge for keeping things simple http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/word-mail-merge-multiple-excel-sheets/ab8ca5e5-de64-4bcc-8a12-01a6289a1e13

Comment: The quick answer is "Yes - it is possible" ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Indicate which language you plan to use. I would suggest C#

Answer (score 0):

Indicate which language you plan to use. I would suggest C#. You might look up for Microsoft.Office.Interop Word and Excel and work with shapes. Another possible solution would be the OOXML, but its way more complexe to understand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document%28v=office.11%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8fc4b3f0-acda-4db0-8b81-56a6157a5f4c
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/fa6ae29a-7a7b-4d4b-a419-3c42706b2b39
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e8ca1e64-f71a-4be9-aa86-9d968910d029
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/58ee824a-7365-4020-90a1-a4a6405d86a7
[Showing HTML in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196954/showing-html-in-powerpoint)

Those are forums which you can visit and find out more about how to open Excel and Powerpoint with C#

Comment: Can any OOP languages. _C#_ is ok, but I don't know how to do it?

Comment: I've edited my comment and added URL's which you can look up for necessary information.