# C# Paste HTML to Excel or PowerPoint

Tags: c#, html, excel, powerpoint

How to paste HTML ( tables ) code into Excel or PowerPoint?

Comment: if you were knowing ans why did you asked?

Comment: @Freelancer its perfectly acceptable to post your own answer. There's even a tickbox for doing that in the questions asking page. Its to help future developers. Admittedly the answer isn't best practice - yet - we'll see if the OP takes feedback on board.

Comment: Need to wait 2 days for tickbox. But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overcome some issues concerning pasting HTML into Excel and PowerPoint and noticed that a lot of people are asking that.

I'd like to share my research, solution I made out for it.

Let's say we have a html file named **html** and we would like to access it in Excel, let's do following:

```
Clipboard.SetText(html);
```

We copy our **html** into the Clipboard. The clipboard generates from the html a real table or image/chart from the input file.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Let's wait a second to have a preview

```
sheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial();
```

Now, we paste the content into a range that we could like to paste it, by defining **cellmap**.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Let's wait a second to see the output

```
sheet.UsedRange.Copy(Missing.Value);
```

Now, in order to copy the table image into PowerPoint, we must work the with **UsedRange.Copy**, because it will copy the currently selected Excel area.

In order to check that we paste it into the correct Powerpoint slide

```
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide slide in presentation.Slides)
{
    foreach (PowerPoint.Shape pptshape in slide.Shapes)
    {
        if(<your condition satisfies>)
        {
            slide.Select(); // some position in any slide
            pptshape.Delete();//delete old content that was in that slide
            ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial(); //paste the Excel content
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there are other solutions, like making an image out of the html code and pasting that, which was my initial idea.

Another post refering that manipulation:
[Showing HTML in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196954/showing-html-in-powerpoint)

Comment: Using fixed sleep times to wait until something is done is a bad practice. Better use callbacks. This might break on slower computers or larger sheets.

Comment: Thanks for the rich information. I have put a timer, because on larger copy/paste tables it requires more time. Didn't know about callbacks, will take a look at it.

Comment: How can i copy the excel range into a shape keeping the source formatting?